# Which Hilbert's 10th polynomials are known to have solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, decidability

The Diophantine equation
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 42$$
was recently solved by
Booker and Sutherland:
[Sum of three cubes for 42 finally solved](https://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2019-09/uob-sot090619.php).

Is there a clean partition of the form of those
polynomial equations all of which *do* have integer solutions,
and those that are known to be undecidable
(following the negative solution of Hilbert's 10th)?
Or—in the absence of a clean partition—can at least
the equations be partitioned into: 
$$\{ \textrm{solvable, undecidable, unknown} \}$$

Am I correct that the status
of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = c$ is unknown
except for certain values of $c$?
I ask this naively; not my expertise.

---

Related MO question:
[What are the solutions of this Diophantine equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/339954/6094).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negative solution of [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) means that there is no algorithm that would recognize the solvable polynomial equations. Hence the "clean partition" you are looking for does not exist.

Of course, one can partition the polynomials any way one likes. The partition solvable/non-solvable/undecidable is a legitimate one, except that one "does not know" which polynomials belong to the individual parts.

Comment: Thank you. I thought e.g., linear Diophantine equations and Pell's equation fell into the "solvable" class, or at least the "understood" class.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Yes, there are well-understood classes of Diophantine equations. However, Matiyasevich's theorem states, in a sense, that we shall never fully understand which equations are solvable/non-solvable/undecidable. Just as we shall never fully understand which statements in number theory are provable/falsifiable/undecidable. We make progress from day to day (this is our job), but we are walking on an infinite path.

Comment: "we are walking on an infinite path"---Well phrased!

Comment: @MarkSapir: Matiyasevich's theorem also implies that there exists polynomials for which solvability is undecidable within ZFC (assuming ZFC is consistent). Indeed, assume that for each polynomial solvability is decidable within ZFC. Then, given an arbitrary polynomial, you can go through the first order statements in ZFC one by one, and after a while you will arrive at a proof or disproof of solvability (because a proof in ZFC is a first order statement in ZFC). This is a general algorithm for solvability, but Matiyasevich proved that such an algorithm does not exist. Contradiction.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Of course you are right that algorithmic undecidability only makes sense for infinite classes of polynomials. The "undecidability within ZFC" is a different kind of notion, but not independent of "algorithmic undecidability" (because ZFC is recursive). This is what I tried to indicate in my remark.

Comment: I am not sure this quite answers the question. Yes, for an arbitrary family of polynomials there is not much more to say, but the polynomials in the question are fairly concrete. Can we say something about the decidability of the resulting equations, even if unfeasible?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: The question was about all polynomial equations, not just about $x^3+y^3+z^3=c$. Note also that the OP accepted my answer.

Comment: @GHfromMO Sure. But, regardless of what Joseph question was, do you know anything about the specific family mentioned in the problem?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: It is conjectured that every integer not congruent to $\pm 4$ modulo $9$ is a sum of three integral cubes. There are a few positive results, but otherwise the status of these equations is unknown (including their possible independence of ZFC).